# How to grant a read-only access to a directory to a user on the command line?

Tags: windows, permissions, command-line-interface

I am trying to grant a read-only access to my temp directory to another user from the command line using icacls.exe.

Tried the following (PowerShell):

- icacls.exe $env:TEMP /grant mydom\user:R
- icacls.exe $env:TEMP /grant 'mydom\user:(GR)'
- icacls.exe $env:TEMP /grant 'mydom\user:(GR,X)'
- icacls.exe $env:TEMP /grant mydom\user:F

No matter what I try when I check the permissions I get the same picture:
[image]

The user is added to the list of the users - fine, but it shows no permissions.

So, what is the right way to do it? Using icacls is not necessary, any  command line way is fine.

Comment: Check the advanced permissions window ;)

Comment: The advanced window shows the rights I am trying to set, but the application that depends on the rights still does not work. It does work, however, when I manually grant the Read and List folder contents in the dialog. So, I want exactly the same effect on the command line

Comment: You could try setting the permissions by hand. Next you run the command 'icacls [folderpath]'. It shows what permissions the user has. You can reuse that syntax.

Comment: @ZEDA-NL - please, arrange your comment as an answer, because it worked! The right permissions turn out to be **(OI)(CI)(RX)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the permissions by hand. Next you run the command 'icacls [folderpath]'. It shows what permissions the user has. You can reuse that syntax.